# Spring Security - Can <security:http> directive be inherited?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on a spring security context like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/path1/**" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" 
        authentication-manager-ref="_authenticationManager1">
    ...

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/path1/login.html*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    ...
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/path2/**" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager2">
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/path2/login.html*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    ...
</security:http>
<security:http pattern="/**" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager1">
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/path1/login.html*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    ...
</security:http>
```

The first directive and the last directive are the same in terms of intercept-urls, the only difference is the url pattern; is there any way I can make the last directive extend the first one?